# what is the purpose of -i in front of scp and ssh commands?

Tags: ssh, scp

What is the "-i" for in the command "scp -i *key* *username*@*address*: *path 1* *path 2*"?

Note: I've seen "-i" used in ssh commands as well.

Comment: Did you try `man ssh` or `man scp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SuSE documentation](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:SCP_usage):

> SCP is based on RCP. It allows the user to copy files over a secure channel between computers. SCP is non interactive, meaning you will have to know where the file is you want to copy and you will have to make sure the destination path exists. It is a nice way to quickly transfer a single file or a directory (in recursive mode) to an other computer. If you are interested in a more interactive way of accessing, downloading and uploading your files, you probably want to use SFTP.

from `man scp`:

> -i identity_file
>
> ```
>          Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for public
>          key authentication is read.  This option is directly passed to
>          ssh
> ```

It's used to point to the file containing your key to be authenticate your secure copy

Comment: what is man? is this just something u can type into the command line?

Comment: man - an interface to the on-line reference manuals. I got this from `man man`

Answer (score 1):

From `scp` man page:

```
-i identity_file
             Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for public
             key authentication is read.  This option is directly passed to
             ssh(1).
```

with `-i` option, `ssh` can know where is your private key to used.

You should read command man page before ask any question.

Comment: Same answer as mine buddy

Comment: It seems we post answer at the same time.

Comment: It's 1 20 sec difference.. Lol Nice man